# FORFILES not including today's files is not working

Tags: batch-file

Reading on the page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/08/03/10334560.aspx

We see that he discusses: the use of /D +0 and it would stand to reason to use /D -0 to not include today's created files.

I am in the midst of working on a web archive project and pretty close on this..

```
FORFILES /P D:\logs\ /M dump.log* /D -0  /C "cmd /c ECHO @file"
FORFILES /P D:\logs\ /M server.log* /D -0  /C "cmd /c ECHO @file"
```

In fact, I get the same results when using either /D -0 or /D +0

Comment: From the `forfiles /?` documentation, `/D` "Selects files with a last modified date... less than **or equal to** (-) the current date minus 'dd' days".  Therefore, `-0` selects all files modified today or earlier, which is to say, no files are excluded.  Use `-1` to select all files excluding today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/D is a date offset. Usually, it is followed by a negative number that indicates that the command should be run on files with a last modified date less than or equal to the specified offset. In extremely rare cases, a `+0` can be used on files whose last modified date is somehow after today.

To ignore today's files when processing, use `/D -1` to process all other files... unless you have files from the future.

Comment: I need to check this..  I thought -1 would be 24 hours ago.  Our server job kicks off a 12:05 AM and we want to archive the files that were created not only yesterday, but any day, just not today.

Comment: This is perfect!  I just used it with great success.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The date selection is

```
/d +date  files with date >= to the indicated date
/d -date  files widh date <= to the indicated date
/d +n     files with date >= to today-n days
/d -n     files with date <= to today-n days
```

So a point in time is picked based in the values of `date` or `n`, and then the `+` or `-` selects if the files selected are newer (`-`) or older (`+`) (or equal on both cases) to the indicated point.

So, to select all files except those changed today `/d -1` should be used. That is, we select the yesterday's date (`1`) and then all files with date lower or equal (`-`) to this point

The `/d +0` will pick the date of today (today - 0) and select the files with date greater or equal (`+`) to the picked date, so, the files selected are those changed today.